Configuring SSL in Quickfix/go locally
I am trying to test quickfix/go locally with TLS, I generated the certs with easyrsa :
git clone https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa.git example-ca
cd example-ca/easyrsa3
./easyrsa init-pki
...
./easyrsa build-ca
...
./easyrsa build-server-full localhost nopass
...
./easyrsa build-client-full 'client0' nopass
...

The configuration of executor is as follow :
[DEFAULT]
ResetOnLogon=Y
FileLogPath=tmp
SocketPrivateKeyFile=config/localhost.key
SocketCertificateFile=config/localhost.crt
SocketCAFile=config/ca.crt
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketMinimumTLSVersion=TLS12

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=EXECUTOR
TargetCompID=CLIENT1
SocketAcceptPort=15000
BeginString=FIX.4.4

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=EXECUTOR
TargetCompID=CLIENT2
SocketAcceptPort=16000
BeginString=FIX.4.4

and on the initiator I have this configuration :
{
  "global": {
      "FileLogPath": "/tmp",
      "MongoStoreConnection": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
      "MongoStoreDatabase": "test_fix",
      "ResetOnLogon": "Y"
  },
  "sessions": [
      {
          "SocketConnectHost": "localhost",
          "SocketConnectPort": "15000",
          "HeartBtInt": "30",
          "ReconnectInterval": "30",
          "BeginString": "FIX.4.4",
          "SenderCompID": "CLIENT1",
          "TargetCompID": "EXECUTOR",
          "SocketPrivateKeyFile": "certs/client0.key",
          "SocketCertificateFile": "certs/client0.crt",
          "SocketCAFile": "certs/ca.crt",
          "SocketUseSSL": "Y",
          "SocketMinimumTLSVersion": "TLS12"
      },
      {
          "SocketConnectHost": "localhost",
          "SocketConnectPort": "16000",
          "HeartBtInt": "30",
          "ReconnectInterval": "30",
          "BeginString": "FIX.4.4",
          "SenderCompID": "CLIENT2",
          "TargetCompID": "EXECUTOR",
          "SocketCAFile": "certs/ca.crt",
          "SocketPrivateKeyFile": "certs/client0.key",
          "SocketCertificateFile": "certs/client0.crt",
          "SocketUseSSL": "Y",
          "SocketMinimumTLSVersion": "TLS12"
      }
  ]
}

This Json format I parse and save the params in each sessions :
sessionConfig.Set(k, s)

but when starting I have message in executor :
|Content:      remote error: tls: bad certificate

How do you generate the right certificates to connect in tls in quickfix/go ?
